# Spark node is not starting in DSE cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

Analytics node seems down.

```
Datacenter: Analytics
=====================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens  Owns    
DN  172.20.10.20  4.44 MB    1       ?       
Datacenter: Cassandra
=====================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens  Owns    
UN  172.20.10.18  281.94 GB  1       ?       
UN  172.20.10.19  281.21 GB  1       ?       
UN  172.20.10.17  281.23 GB  1       ?       
Datacenter: Solr
================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens  Owns    
UN  172.20.10.22  277.97 GB  1       ?      
UN  172.20.10.21  286.75 GB  1       ?
```

So i logged in to that node and trying to start spark

```
        dse cassandra -k
```

But i get the below exception

```
Exception encountered during startup: null
INFO  07:15:58  DSE shutting down...
INFO  07:15:58  All plugins are stopped.
```

Comment: what did you find in the system.log on the spark node? also - did you ever start that node as a regular cassandra node? what version of cassandra is this?